# How do you export history of comments in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

If I just want to review a list of the changes - perhaps give them to my manager or edit them into release notes. How can I do that?

Ideally I'd like a command that: **exports all the comments between revision X & Y into a text file.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need only the comments, then use something like:

```
hg log --template '{desc}\n\n' -r X..Y
```

where X and Y are the revisions for the starting and ending revision, respectively. If you want more context, such as author, date, revision ID, expand the template accordingly, for example:

```
hg log --template 'Author: {author}\nDate: {date|isodate}\nID: {node|short}\n\n{desc}\n-----\n' -r X..Y
```

See `hg help templates` for more details on how to customize the output.

Depending on what you are doing, you may also want the `:` instead of the `..`/`::` range operator. See `hg help revsets` for the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a fine answer, but if you're a traditionalist you can even use changelog format:

```
hg log --style=changelog -r X..Y
```

which gives you something like:

```
2013-11-29  Chris Jerdonek  <chris.jerdonek@gmail.com>

        * mercurial/parsers.c, tests/test-parseindex2.py:
        parsers: fail fast if Python has wrong minor version (issue4110)

        This change causes an informative ImportError to be raised when
        importing the extension module parsers if the minor version of the
        currently-running Python interpreter doesn't match that of the
        Python that was used when compiling the extension module. Here is an
        example of what the new error looks like:

         Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 1, in
        <module> import mercurial.parsers ImportError: Python minor version
        mismatch: The Mercurial extension modules were compiled with Python
        2.7.6, but Mercurial is currently using Python with
        sys.hexversion=33883888: Python 2.5.6 (r256:88840, Nov 18 2012,
        05:37:10) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1
        ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] at: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks
        /Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Resources/
        Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```